# Best practice for creating new responses in a response interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

For `$http` [interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_interceptors) in AngularJS:

> `response`: interceptors get called with http response object. The
>   function is free to modify the response or create a new one. The
>   function needs to return the response directly or as a promise.

What is the best practice for creating a new response? Currently I'm just returning a dummy object:

```
return { config: {}, data: '', headers: function() { return ''; }, status: 403 };
```

That works just fine for my application's needs, but I'm wondering if there is an API to use instead.